# jquery ajax in php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

First time I am trying to use jquery ajax in my php code.
I have a collection of checkboxes. According to my checked checkboxes, the mysql query will be built and it will be showing in my page. Could you please help me how to go forward?

Thanks.

Comment: Try looking through [this checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) and go through (some of) the steps. This will increase your chances of getting a useful answer.

Comment: Without anything else to go on, keep in mind that an ajax request is exactly the same as any other request from the server's point of view. The only difference is that it's triggered by javascript on the client-side, and the response is not displayed by the browser, but intercepted by javascript on the client-side. So build the query the same way you'd do it if it was posted from a form, the only thing different is the jQuery.ajax() call which you can learn about from their docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the manual [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). There you have several examples as well.

You must collect your checkboxes values and then send that to your PHP script

```
var cb1 = $('#checkbox1').attr('checked');
var cb2 = $('#checkbox2').attr('checked');
$.ajax({ type: 'POST',
         url: 'checkboxes.php',
         data: { checkbox1: cb1,
                 checkbox2: cb2 },
         success: function(response) {
                  // do something with response from PHP script
                 }
       });
```

See the jQuery API for more options you can use.

On the server side, you evaluate the `$_POST` variable as with any other request.